# Why is my OpenMP implementation slower than a single threaded implementation?

Tags: c, openmp

I am learning about OpenMP concurrency, and tried my hand at some existing code I have. In this code, I tried to make all the for loops parallel. However, this seems to make the program MUCH slower, at least 10x slower, or even more than the single threaded version.

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/zyLzuWU2

I also used pthreads, which turns out to be faster than the single threaded version.

Now the question is, what am I doing wrong in my OpenMP implementation that is causing this slowdown?

Thanks!

edit: the single threaded version is just the one without all the #pragmas

Comment: Are you running it on a single core system?

Comment: unless you're using no more than 1 thread per core, they're likely to be competing with each other for shared resources. Introducing parallelization doesn't automatically make programs run faster.

Comment: @matt: perhaps you can write an answer stating that and perhaps some workaround suggestions? thanks!

Comment: You have pragmas in your code that are not correct and are ignored - but you should understand the OpenMP concepts.  The pragmas I am talking about are the "#pragma omp end".  The OpenMP pragmas apply to structured blocks in C/C++ and as such do not need an end pragma.  It is only in Fortran where you don't have the block ({}) denoted that you need to use end directives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem I see with your code is that you are using OpenMP across loops that are very small (8 or 64 iterations, for example).  This will not be efficient due to overheads.  If you want to use OpenMP for the n-queens problem, look at OpenMP 3.0 tasks and thread parallelism for branch-and-bound problems.

Comment: Tasking requires you to look at how you are parallelizing differently.  However, there are several papers and presentations on the web showing almost a linear speedup (2 threads being twice as fast as serial, 4 threads being almost 4 times as fast as serial, etc) when using OpenMP tasking to parallelize the nqueens problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think your code is much too complex to be reviewed here. One error that I saw immediately is that it is not even correct. At places where you are using an `omp parallel for` to do sums you must use `reduction(+: yourcountervariable)` to have the results of the different threads correctly assembled together. Otherwise one thread may overwrite the result of the others.

Comment: The correct clause is "reduction(+: yourCounterVariable)".  Without this or using atomic, critical, or locks your results aren't even correct.

Answer (score 2):

At least two reasons:

1. You're only doing 8 iterations of a very simple loop.  Your runtime will be completely dominated by the overhead involved in setting up all the threads.
2. In some places, the `critical` section will cause contention; all the threads will be trying to access the critical section continuously, and block each other.