# Why is my OpenMP implementation slower than a single threaded implementation? (Followup)

Tags: c, openmp

This is a follow up to [Why is my OpenMP implementation slower than a single threaded implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042351/why-is-my-openmp-implementation-slower-than-a-single-threaded-implementation) .

I have adhered to the answer provided, and used tasking instead of for pragmas to speed up the code. However, compared to a sequential (same) program, both programs run equally as fast. I witness no speed up.

The reworked code is here: http://pastebin.com/3SFaNEc4

I simply removed all the for pragmas and replaced it tasking pragmas for the recursive procedures.

Am I doing anything wrong? I should be seeing an almost linear speed up. What do you guys think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - you still have an "#pragma end critical" which should be removed.  It isn't causing a problem, but it is incorrect.  Second - as I said in the other question you posted, you might have to think about how you are parallelizing the code to see the speedup, so just replacing the other pragmas with task pragmas may not speed it up.  Third - you haven't put the tasks into a parallel region, so you are not running in parallel at all.  And you can't just add a parallel region around the tasks or you are going to be doing the same tasks multiple times.

Comment: i don't get the part about putting the tasks in parallel, i've look at examples and it doesn't seem required, you sure about that? also, i didnt just replace, i made the recursive procedures into tasks.

Comment: I don't know what examples you have been looking at - but yes I am sure that if you want the tasks to be run in parallel in OpenMP then they have to be within a parallel region.  The parallel region says that you are going to run multiple threads and that is when the threads are set up.  The tasks are put into a pool and then the threads pick them up and execute them.  That is why I said you can't just surround the tasks with a region, because then every thread will run every task.

Comment: Look at the OpenMP V3.0 spec, example A.13.5c and A.13.10c. These show the entire region. The other examples show the tasking but not the surrounding parallel region. I guess the examples might need some further explanation. I will make note of that for the V3.1 review going on.